# Wistia api remove video from dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, dom, wistia

I am using async embed with wistia: https://wistia.com/doc/embed-options#using_embed_options

```
<script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>

<div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_g5pnf59ala></div>

window._wq = window._wq || [];

_wq.push({ id: "g5pnf59ala", onReady: function(video) {
        console.log('onReady')

}});
```

The problem is when I want to remove video, I use their api remove method: https://wistia.com/doc/player-api#remove before I remove the div class="wistia_embed from the dom. Then later in my script if I do this process again, add this div to dom:

```
<div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_g5pnf59ala></div>
```

and use:

```
_wq.push({ id: "g5pnf59ala", onReady: function(video) {
        console.log('onReady')

}});
```

onReady event fires twice.

I tried doing

```
window._wq = [];
```

However this doesnt help.

**I need to remove div from the dom, I need such solution to work. And later if  I need it again, I need to add it again.**

How do I clean reference to previous video in their _wq ?

You can see the problem here:

https://jsfiddle.net/5z5j3g2x/1/

Comment: Ever found a solution?